# SQL Filtrar relacion muchos a muchos según varios valores sobre el mismo campo

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo las tablas personas, materias y personas_materias con una relacion muchos a muchos. 
Necesito hacer un query para seleccionar personas que estan en dos materias diferentes.

[image]

Ejemplo de lo que he probado

```
SELECT *
FROM persona p        
JOIN personas_materias pm1 ON p.id = pm1.idPersona        
JOIN materia m1 ON pm1.idMateria = m1.id AND m1.nombre = 'INGLES' 
JOIN personas_materias pm2 ON p.id = pm2.idPersona 
JOIN materia m2 ON pm2.idMateria = m2.id AND m2.nombre = 'MATEMATICA'
```

Pero lo estoy plantenado mal porque no funciona. Me podrían guiar un poco? 
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esta consulta

```
SELECT
    materia.nombre as Materia materia.nombre as Persona
FROM
    materia m
    INNER JOIN personas_materias pm ON m.id = pm.idMateria
    INNER JOIN persona p ON p.id = pm.idPersona
```

en caso que quieras agregar una condición solo tienes que agregar un `where` a la consulta

```
SELECT
    materia.nombre as Materia materia.nombre as Persona
FROM
    materia m
    INNER JOIN personas_materias pm ON m.id = pm.idMateria
    INNER JOIN persona p ON p.id = pm.idPersona
WHERE
    m.nombre = "MATEMATICA"
```

Answer (score 0):

he replicado tu modelo y estos son los datos de prueba con los que he trabajado:

Tabla de materias con los siguientes datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla de Usuarios con los siguientes datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le he asignado 3 materias al usuario con id 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y finalmente con un inner simple, he capturado los datos de todos los usuarios en la tabla de relación. Claro, aquí puedes hacer los where que necesites, pero los inner que necesitas son los que están en la siguiente query:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes diferentes maneras de realizar esta consulta. La primera es utilizando `JOIN` y la segunda `SUBQUERIES`. De lo que entiendo, necesitas obtener una lista de personas que están matriculadas en INGLES y MATEMATICAS. Si esto es correcto, te envío las siguientes consultas:

**1. JOIN:** utilizando JOIN, los registros se multiplicarán por la cantidad de materias que tenga una persona. Es decir, si John Doe está matriculado en 2 materias, aparecerá 2 veces. Si Jane Doe esta en 4 materias, aparecerá 4 veces.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM persona p        
JOIN personas_materias pm1 ON p.id = pm1.idPersona        
JOIN materia m1 ON pm1.idMateria = m1.id AND m1.nombre IN ('INGLES', 'MATEMATICA')
```

```sql
SELECT *
FROM persona p        
JOIN personas_materias pm1 ON p.id = pm1.idPersona        
JOIN materia m1 ON pm1.idMateria = m1.id
WHERE m1.nombre IN ('INGLES', 'MATEMATICA')
```

**2. SUBQUERIES**: Con subqueries y la condición EXISTS te permitirá mostrar los registros de la tabla `persona` que cumplan con la condición del subquery.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM persona p 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM personas_materias pm1      
JOIN materia m1 ON pm1.idMateria = m1.id
WHERE pm1.idPerson = p.id AND m1.nombre IN ('INGLES', 'MATEMATICA')
)
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Esto lo he probado pero me retorna Ingles OR Matematica. Necesito Ingles AND Matemática.